# ASP MVC3 - How to load a custom user defined layout for the page from a database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have online form builder appplication in ASP.NET MVC3 with Razor views.
It is similar to this - https://examples.wufoo.com/forms/workshop-registration/

I need users to be able to customize the page design. 
Not only to upload a custom css, but also to customize the HTML page template. 
Let's say users should have complete control on Layout's HTML for their custom webform page. User should be able to edit any HTML on the page, beside the form that is included into the layout.

I'm not sure how to do that with Razor and ASP.NET MVC 3.
Is it possible to:

1. load layout somewhere from database as string or whatever
2. replace some custom tags like "FORM1_INCLUDE" to 
   @Html.Partial("some_non_customizable_layout_for_form1")
3. use the result as a valid Layout file for the user's form page

Maybe 1-3 is not the best way to do what I need. 
What can you suggest for such user defined page layout approach in ASP.NET MVC 3 with Razor views?

**UPDATE 1**
Using VirtualPathProvider I was able to load View from database, but it just returns text like:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
<body>
@Html.EditorFor(z => z.Customer)
</body>
```

and doesn't process any Razor syntax at all. 
What could be the problem with it?

*SOLVED:*

Needed to place this line as the first one in Application_Start() method:

```
HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new MyVirtualPathProvider());
```

**UPDATE 2**
Custom View Provider is registered in Global.asax.cs as:

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new MyVirtualPathProvider());

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
```

MyVirtualPathProvider code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Hosting;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace new_frontend
{
    public class MyVirtualPathProvider : VirtualPathProvider
    {
        public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath)
        {
            var td = FindTemplate(virtualPath);
            if (td == null)
            {
                return true;
                //return base.FileExists(virtualPath);
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath)
        {
            var td = FindTemplate(virtualPath);
            if (td == null)
            {
                return new MyVirtualFile(virtualPath, "");
                //return base.GetFile(virtualPath);
            }
            else
            {
                return new MyVirtualFile(virtualPath, td.ContentStep1);
            }
        }

        private Facade.Dto.TemplateData FindTemplate(string virtualPath)
        {
            string prefix = "Template#";

            int id = 0;
            Facade.Dto.TemplateData td = null;

            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(virtualPath);
            if (fileName.StartsWith(prefix))
                Int32.TryParse(fileName.Substring(prefix.Length), out id);

            if (id > 0)
                td = Facade.FrontEndServices.GetTemplate(id);

            return td;
        }
    }

    public class MyVirtualFile : VirtualFile
    {
        private byte[] data;

        public MyVirtualFile(string virtualPath, string body)
            : base(virtualPath)
        {                      // 'System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationStartPage
            string _body = /*body +*/ @"

@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(""Submit"", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = ""main"" }))
{
}
<!-- <PERSONAL_INFO> -->
<div id=""personal_info"" class=""op2-block"">

</div>
<!-- <PERSONAL_INFO> -->";

            this.data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_body);
        }

        public override System.IO.Stream Open()
        {
            return new MemoryStream(data);
        }
    }
}
```

And now for the Razor view code defined as a string above I get this exception:

*"Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.AjaxHelper' does not contain a definition for 'BeginForm' and no extension method 'BeginForm' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.AjaxHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"*

And when I changed Razor View code to:

```
string _body = /*body +*/ @"

@using System.Web.WebPages;
@using System.Web.Mvc;
@using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
@using System.Web.Routing;

@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<dynamic>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(""Submit"", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = ""main"" }))
{
}
<!-- <PERSONAL_INFO> -->
<div id=""ppg_op2_personal_info"" class=""op2-block"">

</div>
<!-- <PERSONAL_INFO> -->";
```

I got a different error:

Type 'ASP._Page__appstart_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationStartPage'

When I change

@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage

to

@inherits System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationStartPage

to fix the error above, I get a new one:

*"Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Ajax' does not exist in the current context"*

**UPDATE3:**
I tried to use base.XXX:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Hosting;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace new_frontend
{
    public class MyVirtualPathProvider : VirtualPathProvider
    {
        public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath)
        {
            var td = FindTemplate(virtualPath);
            if (td == null)
            {
                //return true;
                return base.FileExists(virtualPath);
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath)
        {
            var td = FindTemplate(virtualPath);
            if (td == null)
            {
                //return new MyVirtualFile(virtualPath, "");
                return base.GetFile(virtualPath);
            }
            else
            {
                return new MyVirtualFile(virtualPath, td.ContentStep1);
            }
        }

        private Facade.Dto.TemplateData FindTemplate(string virtualPath)
        {
            string prefix = "Template#";

            int id = 0;
            Facade.Dto.TemplateData td = null;

            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(virtualPath);
            if (fileName.StartsWith(prefix))
                Int32.TryParse(fileName.Substring(prefix.Length), out id);

            if (id > 0)
                td = Facade.FrontEndServices.GetTemplate(id);

            return td;
        }
    }

    public class MyVirtualFile : VirtualFile
    {
        private byte[] data;

        public MyVirtualFile(string virtualPath, string body)
            : base(virtualPath)
        {                      // 'System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationStartPage
            string _body = /*body +*/ @"

@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<PPG.Facade.Dto.NewOrderPageData>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(""Submit"", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = ""main"" }))
{
}
<!-- <PERSONAL_INFO> -->
<div id=""personal_info"" class=""op2-block"">

</div>
<!-- <PERSONAL_INFO> -->";

            this.data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_body);
        }

        public override System.IO.Stream Open()
        {
            return new MemoryStream(data);
        }
    }
}
```

In this case I get a view that is not parsed at all, this is what I get in the web browser:

```
@using System.Web.WebPages;    
@using System.Web.Mvc;    
@using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;    
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html;    
@using System.Web.Routing;    
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<PPG.Facade.Dto.NewOrderPageData>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Submit", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "main" }))
{
}
<!-- <PERSONAL_INFO> -->
<div id="ppg_op2_personal_info" class="op2-block">
</div>
<!-- <PERSONAL_INFO> -->
```

Comment: How are you using your views? You should not use your provider directly, but register it instead of the default one.

Comment: @gauffin I created UPDATE2 to answer the question about the usage of the view.

Comment: There can only be one VirtualPathProvider. You need to invoke `base.XXXX` for all files that you can't handle. Also: All your views must inherit `@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<Namespace.YourModelName>` to be strongly typed.

Comment: base.XXXX - sure. But it's not related to the problems that described above. @inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<Namespace.YourModelName> This is the first thing I tried. The problems described above happens with strongly typed views and without them.

Comment: This error: *Type 'ASP.Page_appstart_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationStartPage* is very strange. It happens when I use `@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<Namespace.AnyModel>` or just `@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`

Comment: `base.XXX` ***IS*** related to the problems above. Fix both things and you'll see.

Comment: @jgauffin I tried to use base.XXX (UPDATE3) now the template is not parsed and browser displays initial Razor template's code. No clue why it happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should create a virtual path provider which fetches your custom views from a database.

There are several questions here about them. Just search for VirtualPathProvider

**Updates (from my comments to the question discussion)**

- The VirtualPathProvider must be registered in Application_Start using `HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new MyVirtualPathProvider());`
- The base class MUST be called for all files that you can't currently serve. This is required since there can only be one `VirtualPathProvider`. (You'll see lots of strange errors otherwise)
- `@model` directive doesn't work in files that you serve. You must use `@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<YourNameSpace.YourModelName>` instead.
- IIRC you also need to override `GetCacheDependency` and return `null` for your own resources.

Comment: I followed all of this. The result is in my update3. Now the Razor template is displayed in the browsers without parsing. Looks like I miss something simple here...

Comment: Just checked my own provider. Check my last bullet.

Comment: The extension of virtualview's custom file matters. it should be .cshtml after changing it - started to parse file.

Answer (score 0):

depending on the degree of flexibility and customization you wish to give this can be a very simple to a very time consuming task.

If you want users to simply customize the HTML on the page then you can use a WYSIWYG editor and store the raw html in the database.

In the view, use

```
@Html.Raw(Model.body) // Where body is the field containing the wysiwyg content
```

This will render the markup as-is.

To include custom tag / replacement you will have to define a list of string constants that can be inserted while using the WYSIWYG editor. These can then be search - replaced when displaying.

For example in your controller or model:

```
model.body.replace("$[form1]", "<form action='something' method='post' name='form1'></form>");
```

Of course depending on the nature of your application you might want to re-factor this into some sort of tag => markup conversion which will allow you to add more custom tags and their respective real HTML markups.

Hope this helps, Cheers!

Comment: @Html.Raw() doesn't support Mvc helpers such as Html and Url. And it's required, because form is built using Mvc helpers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use something like this:

http://vibrantcode.com/blog/2010/11/16/hosting-razor-outside-of-aspnet-revised-for-mvc3-rc.html

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar & you may fine that XML is very useful. You save the layout definition as XML to the DB. That means it's easy to manipulate, either directly or by serialise/deserialise into an object model.

When you want to display the page, use XSLT to transform your XML into HTML, applying styles etc to the output.

Comment: XML with XSLT will not work here. Users who will edit the layout want to use HTML. Actually they will place the HTML page design from their own site to make the form page on my site look similar to their site when they redirect visitors to the form page.